# Em quais casos trabalhar com mais de um banco em php?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados

Estou trabalhando em cima de de um sistema onde mais de uma empresa terá seu espaço e quero fazer algo em que as empresas cadastrem seus produtos e os visitantes(usuários) possam antes de tudo ver todas as empresas e clicando em uma delas ver seus produtos.

Pensei em utilizar um banco para cada empresa, ou apenas uma tabala organizando as empresas e com o codigo delas inserindo os produtos para identificar cada empresa em respectivos produtos.

Qual a melhor forma ? Alguém que já passou por isso poderia me dar uma força ?

Obrigado desde já pela atenção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito eu que a melhor forma é trabalhar com tabelas, e não um banco para cada empresa.

Pois um banco para cada empresa, significa conexões diferentes no banco de dados para acessar dados de cada empresa, isso com o tempo pode se tornar confuso e complexo os backups, manutenção de banco, imagina você for atualizar uma tabela do seu sistema, e você tem 3 mil empresas cadastradas, então isso significa 3 mil banco de dados, atualizar as tabelas de 3 mil banco de dados é realmente inviável pois você acaba perdendo o controle de seu sistema.

Comment: Valeu cara, precisava disso !

Comment: cara posso tirar uma duvida ?
Assim, por ser tudo tratado um um unico banco, tem perigo de acontecer troca de dados ? eu penso quando tiver varios usuarios cadastrando de diferentes empresas. Há a possibilidade de acontecer uma troca de dados ?

Comment: Troca de dados, você quer dizer, dado de uma empresa X ser cadastrado em uma empresa Y? Se for isso, depende unicamente da sua modelação de banco e aforma como você vai programar, no caso isso seria algo como um BUG ou falha, você tem que programar seu sistema de forma que isso nunca seja possível acontecer. Você tem conhecimentos suficientes em banco de dados? SQL, como criar uma query, fazer um select especifico, um insert, etc? Se não recomendo você estudar fortemente isso, antes de tentar modelar seu sistema.

Comment: Tenho sim esse conhecimento, muito obrigado cara ! Valeu mesmo

Comment: Neste caso até seria interessante você trabalhar com mais de um banco de dados, porém o ideal é que seja um cluster com 2 databases, um banco de dados de leitura e um de escrita, onde os dados do DB de escrita sejam replicados no banco de dados de leitura, assim você terá uma performance melhor em ambas as operações (Escritas e Leitura).

Comment: Em relação a sua pergunta referente ao possível registro de dados trocados por engano, você precisa modelar seu banco de dados com pelo menos duas tabelas que se relacionam com uma cardinalidade 1 -> N por exemplo, tabela empresa e tabela produto, onde na tabela empresa uma empresa teria um único registro, e na tabela produtos você usa uma chave estrangeira referenciando esta empresa em cada produto pertencente a ela. Se você tiver dúvida pesquise no google por modelagem de cardinalidade 1 para N. Você deverá encontrar exemplos mais didáticos deste cenário de modelo de dados.